# Cannot Set Programmatic Layout Constraints in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uistackview

I am trying to center radiobuttons in UIStackView that I have created via the storyboard. However, the radiobuttons are created within the UIStackView programmatically based on data in Firebase.

I am using the library offered at [DLRadioButtons](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton).

UIStackView below Label, named radioStackView:[image]

Code where Radio Buttons are added based on Firebase Data:

```
  `
    pollRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.numberOfChildren = Int(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childrenCount)
    self.passLabel.text = String(self.numberOfChildren)
    print(self.numberOfChildren)

    var buttons = [DLRadioButton]()

      for x in 0..<self.numberOfChildren {
    let answerLabel = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childSnapshot(forPath: String(x+1)).childSnapshot(forPath: "answer").value
    let firstRadioButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y:1 , width: 80.0, height: 1.0), title: answerLabel as! String, color: UIColor.black)
        firstRadioButton.tag = x
        firstRadioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buttons.append(firstRadioButton)
        let margins = self.radioStackView.layoutMarginsGuide
        firstRadioButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.radioStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstRadioButton)
        }


    let groupButtons = DLRadioButton()
    groupButtons.otherButtons = buttons
    })



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

`
Output: Buttons not stacking directly on top of each other; tried playing with interface builder but still unable to remove spacing
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stack views in a `stackView` you need to use [addArrangedSubview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616227-addarrangedsubview)

```
self.radioStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstRadioButton)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have updated the code. I cannot get the buttons to now stack directly on top of each other. Any thoughts?

Comment: check the [spacing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview/1616225-spacing) property

Comment: I did with the interface builder, I am playing around with those settings and the spacing is not changing.

Comment: `stackView` works with constraints, so you have to either set height constraint for all `arrangedSubviews` or for the `stackView` itself

Comment: Thanks, I have added programmatic constraints (top Anchor) but I am now getting a runtime error. Appreciate your help.